# Find target bundle(s) for a specific entityreference field

Tags: 7, entities

I am creating a simple administration page that shows all content types and some details about each content type field.

- I am getting the list of content types with `node_type_get_types()`
- I am getting the list of fields with `field_info_instances()`

When the widget module is `entityreference` I'd like to display the target bundle(s) of that entity reference field.

```
foreach(node_type_get_types() as $value) {

  $fields = field_info_instances('node', $value->type);

  // Loop through fields
  foreach($fields as $field) {

    if ($field['widget']['module'] == 'entityreference') {

      // Get the target bundle(s) for this field
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help on that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. I found a solution. I can get them with `field_info_field()`:

```
foreach(node_type_get_types() as $value) {

  $fields = field_info_instances('node', $value->type);

  // Loop through fields
  foreach($fields as $field) {

    if ($field['widget']['module'] == 'entityreference') {

      // Get the target bundle(s) for this field
      $field_info_field = field_info_field($field['field_name']);
      $target_bundles = $field_info_field['settings']['handler_settings']['target_bundles'];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, would you mind to mark your answer as the accepted answer? This would help to connect the information together.

Comment: @leymannx done!

Answer (score 2):

Drupal 8 version:

```
$bundles = \Drupal::entityManager()
->getAllBundleInfo()['node'];
 foreach ($bundles as $id => $value) {
 $node_fields = \Drupal::entityManager()
  ->getFieldDefinitions('node', $id);
   foreach ($node_fields as $field) {
      if ($field instanceof \Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig) {
        if ($field->getType() == 'entity_reference') {
          $target_bundle = $field->getSettings()['handler_settings']['target_bundles'];
          kint($target_bundle);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

With `$target_bundle`, You can do something like this as well to filter out a specific bundle:

```
if ($target_bundle != null && key($target_bundle) == 'mybundle'){
  kint($field->id());
}
```